# How to load method after some time on the click of the button?

Tags: android, button, handler

I load method in the on click of the button but it does not take the time which i given to perfrom action.can anyone tell me what i do wrong.

This is the on click of the button:-

```
resand_otp_new.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {



                if (VerificationCount < 2) {
                    if(br != null)
                   {
                        br.show();
                   }
                    checkotp.setText("");


                    HashMap<String, String> formData = new HashMap<>();
                    formData.put("Phone", Phone);
                    webServiceHandler.requestToServer((getResources().getString(R.string.api_end_point)) + "SendOTPForgetPassword", WebService.ADDLIST, formData, true);


                    VerificationCount++;
                    timer.start();
                    mTvCountDown.setText("00:00:30");
                    resand_otp_new.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    verifyResendOtp();


                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "You Have Used Maximum Chances of OTP !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


            }
        });
```

I load method verifyResendOtp() for the 30 second.but it does not take time it execute instantly.

This is my method :-

```
private void verifyResendOtp() {

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (generalUtilities.isConnected()) {
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(IncominMsg.KEY_PREFERNCE, MODE_PRIVATE);
                otpnumber = sharedPreferences.getString(IncominMsg.KEY_OTP, "");
                Log.e("otpnumberverifiy....", otpnumber);

                checkotp.setText(otpnumber);

                HashMap<String, String> formData = new HashMap<>();
                formData.put("Phone", Phone);
                formData.put("OTP", checkotp.getText().toString().trim());
                webServiceHandler.requestToServer((getResources().getString(R.string.api_end_point)) + "CheckOTPForgetPassword", WebService.FORGET_PASSWORD, formData, true);


            } else {

                generalUtilities.showAlertDialog("HEY USER", "Please Connect To the Internet", getApplicationContext());
            }

        }
    }, 30000);

}
```

Comment: One thing to note here is that each button click will make a new `Handler` instance and schedule a delayed action hence, this approach is slightly flawed.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a design mistake here rather than implementing the Handler inside the method, why don't you create a Handler inside the onClickListener and make implement the runnable and call the method from there.

Something like below

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
        public void run() {
            verifyResendOtp();
        }
}, 30000);
```

And your refactored method

```
private void verifyResendOtp() {
    if (generalUtilities.isConnected()) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(IncominMsg.KEY_PREFERNCE, MODE_PRIVATE);
            otpnumber = sharedPreferences.getString(IncominMsg.KEY_OTP, "");
            Log.e("otpnumberverifiy....", otpnumber);

            checkotp.setText(otpnumber);

            HashMap<String, String> formData = new HashMap<>();
            formData.put("Phone", Phone);
            formData.put("OTP", checkotp.getText().toString().trim());
            webServiceHandler.requestToServer((getResources().getString(R.string.api_end_point)) + "CheckOTPForgetPassword", WebService.FORGET_PASSWORD, formData, true);


        } else {

            generalUtilities.showAlertDialog("HEY USER", "Please Connect To the Internet", getApplicationContext());
        }
}
```

Comment: How is this different from what OP is doing currently?